# Bootstrap nav and navbar classes aren't displaying properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For example, here I have nav-justified as a nav class which should spread the links evenly across the width of the screen.

```
<nav id="header" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>

<div id="main" class="container"> Content</div>

<div id="footer" class="container">
    <p>&copy;
        <time datetime="2018">2018</time> JT </p>
</div>

<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

But instead it does this:

Screenshot of links justified to the left and not centered:

[image]

My main.js is empty and my main.css is only changing the background-color. Both my bootstrap.min.js and bootsrtap.min.css are linked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine in the snippet below using Bootstrap 4.1.2. Have you checked in the developer tools to be sure that you don't have any conflicting style rules?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav id="header" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>

<div id="main" class="container"> Content</div>

<div id="footer" class="container">
  <p>&copy;
    <time datetime="2018">2018</time> JT </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I had to link bootstrap.bundle.min.js instead of bootstrap.min.js